# Put <select> in table cell using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Given input data such as

```
var m2 = [
    ["first",["11975", "5871", "8916", "2868"]],
    ["second",["1951", "10048", "2060", "6171", "99999"]],
    ["third",["8010", "16145", "8090", "8045"]],
    ["fourth",["1013", "990", "940", "6907"]]
];
```

I would like to create a table with two columns. The column on the left would contain the words, and the column on the right would contain a select element, with options to choose among the associated numbers. I.e. the select box of the top row would allow you to choose among the options, ["11975", "5871", "8916", "2868"].

I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/borbash/7WBZj/) that almost does it, but somewhere is going wrong. The options are blank, and it seems that the number of options for each word equals the number of letters in the word!

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to pick a subpart of a D3 selection (in your case the second column), you need to use

```
mySelection.filter(function(d, i) {...});
```

instead of

```
mySelection.select(function(d, i) {...});
```

Finally, you also forgot to add the "text" for every `option` within your `select` tags.

I have updated [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7WBZj/26/).